# Is this small hand tool with a heart-shaped end a woodworking tool?

Tags: hand-tools

This tool is about 5-1/2 inches long including the handle. The tool has a "V" shape. The outer metal sides of the V are beveled on top, with sharp outer edges. The V is bent about 15 degrees or so at the point where its two sides join (and join with the top piece).

It was found with some other tools of my parents. I don't recall seeing it used though. I'm guessing it could be sharp enough to be a small plane for woodworking, or a carving tool.

[image: Top View of Tool]

[image: Close-up of tool]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wDgb.jpg]

Comment: It looks a bit like a gardening tool

Comment: Can we see the other face of the end? Curious what it looks like where the  metal meets on the other side.

Comment: It almost looks like a plane for getting into small corners. The wings appear to be sharpened.

Comment: I wonder if it's used for seaming linoleum or some other surface. The split blade in the center makes me think it's for joining/fitting something fabric like.

Comment: As it turns out this is not a wood working tool. This question should be closed.

Answer (score 9):

It's a grapefruit segmenter
[https://www.amazon.com/Grapefruit-Segmenter-Slicer-Wooden-Handle/dp/B00KRFJJYQ?ie=UTF8&](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KRFJJYQ)*Version*=1&*entries*=0

Comment: Bravo and Thank You.  All us wooden-headed wood workers were struggling to figure this tool out.  Turns out it was probably just in the wrong box.

Comment: I spent a couple of hours trying to discover a sewing or crafts use for this thing (get a life?)- no luck.  Great call.

Answer (score 2):

It looks very similar to a winged weeder

[image]

or a heart-shaped hoe

[image]

Comment: It certainly looks like this tool. Just wish we could find one of the same design.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments it looks more like a gardening tool, the metal going to the tip looks to thin, and it does look sharp. I would say, if you wanted, go take a random piece of wood and see if it removes anything. But I am sure it is a gardening tool.